# MySQL CONCAT_WS not working with foreign keys

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation

I'm generating an identifier column in order to group subscriptions. The value of the column uses `CONCAT_WS` to concatenate different column values from within the table. However, I get an error when trying to alter the table:

`Database error code: 1215`

`Database error: Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Here's the query in question. Note that `organisation_id` and `order_id` are foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `subscriptions`
ADD COLUMN `identifier` VARCHAR(191) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CONCAT_WS('-', `organisation_id`, `is_trial`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `order_id`, `superseded_date`)
) STORED;
```

I tried both `CONCAT` and `CONCAT_WS`, as well as removing the foreign keys from the query. There were no errors when I didn't include the foreign keys in the concatenation.

Comment: Please run `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us what it reports.

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.33

Comment: It seems to work fine on 8.0.30 in this Dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/QhbFE3on I tested it on my local instance of 8.2.0, and it also works fine. Can you please take a look at the Dbfiddle and clarify if anything is different? I had to make some assumptions.

Comment: [Old bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88111)

Comment: Can you connect to the database with a query client? You should be able to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` to confirm the columns and keys and so on, no matter how they were created.

Comment: @BillKarwin The bug occurs when the foreign key has `ON DELETE CASCADE`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/l8UeFgQt

Answer (score 2):

This is a known restriction. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) says:

> A foreign key constraint on the base column of a stored generated column cannot use CASCADE, SET NULL, or SET DEFAULT as ON UPDATE or ON DELETE referential actions.

Your workaround options seem to be:

- Remove the foreign key constraints.
- Remove the `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` options of the foreign keys.
- Remove the `STORED` option of the generated column.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try these out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as #Connor Gyde. I replaced STORED option with VIRTUAL and then it worked fine. Thanks #Barmar